# Msbuild pack task

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-task

I have command like this

```
msbuild /t:pack Test.csproj /p:Authors="Test"
```

Getting error :

> Id is required

Why is not use $(AssemblyName)? And how to fix It?

Comment: what kind of project is that? can you share the csproj?

Comment: It should be using the AssemblyName, that's the default. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets